# Problems in declaring a variable as Byte in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables, byte, variable-declaration

I'm trying out a program which I found on the net. Why is it necessary to put to curly braces at the end of the statement? It gives an error: "Byte has no constructors".

```
Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}
```

I can't put the code like this either, it produces the error "byte cannot be a 1-dimensional array".

```
Dim arr As Byte() = New Byte()
```

Can you explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need curly braces, because if you don't put them, it means you're trying to call a constructor for a *single* object -- which is an error for different reasons:

1. You can't assign a single object to an array. (This is always true.)
2. `Byte` doesn't have a constructor. (This is only true in this particular case.)

Comment: When you said `As Byte()` instead of `As Byte`.

Comment: LOL, I didn't even knew that represented an array initialization. I have a long way to go :P

Comment: @abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz: Haha okay... if you're using Visual Basic 2008 or later, then you can use type inference and omit the `As Byte()` part entirely -- that way, the variable will have the same type as whatever you assign it.

Comment: @Mehrdad: [Type Inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163345.aspx) stuff sounds easy. Thanks mate :) + 1

Comment: Ugh, I just removed my up-vote because you recommended type inference in VB.NET. That's a *very* bad idea. It doesn't work exactly the same way as `var` in C#. Just learn how to declare variables and what the appropriate syntax is. It's not that hard. If you don't know the difference between an array and an object, you're going to have a lot of problems anyway. No reason to create *additional* ones by programming with Option Infer On.

Comment: @Cody: I don't mind the vote issue, but what's the difference between `Dim` and `var`? And what sorts of problems arise with `Dim`? It's not like I recommended Option Explicit Off...

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't think it's a particularly good practice for beginners. If you don't understand the code you're writing, letting the compiler automagically take care of it for you is *not* the way you're going to learn to write better code. If you prefer coding that way, that's fine. (I personally like the compiler to alert me to any possible errors I might have made; Option Strict is yet another way of enabling this. But I also compile C++ at warning level 4.)

Comment: @Cody: I also compile C++ at level 4, and I also turn all on warnings. And I see your point about how this isn't a good thing for a beginner to use. But that's a different question -- my question was, how is `Dim` different from `var`, since you mentioned those are different?

Comment: @Mehrdad: The most important difference is that `Dim` has multiple meanings in VB. If you don't set your project settings exactly the right way, you'll end up where everything is declared as an `Object`. You need to have Option Strict On and Option Infer Off. The article linked to by the OP doesn't make this clear, and in fact almost so much as encourages you to compile with Option Strict Off. You can't break things nearly this badly with `var`.

Comment: @Cody: But just because `Dim` can have more meanings than `var` doesn't mean that it doesn't do the same thing... it just has a superset of the features, not a different set of features. :) Furthermore, aren't Option Explicit, Option Strict, and Option Infer always On by default in recent versions of Visual Studio? (I think they're at least on by default in 2010, and I don't remember 2008.) So I don't think he can really shoot himself in the foot unless he tries to turn off those options... and that would be a bit beyond the scope of things here.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I start evaluating things by the tendency of people to screw them up. Maybe that's cynical or something, but it works for me. I think Option Infer On is "bad practice" in general because it increases the tendency for mistakes. The fact that they're on by default is a good thing. You have to go messing with them to make `Dim` work like `var`. I think that's a bad thing. I don't really know how else to justify this... I've had plenty of bugs crop up because of it; there's no switch for Option PerfectDev On, so we fall back to what the IDE does give us.

Comment: @Cody: I'm confused, though -- if *all* the Option switches are on by default, then you can't screw up, can you? (I don't remember ever being able to screw up with **all** of those options set to On, since the compiler always complained... do you have an example? Maybe I've forgotten.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yeah I don't really remember either. I've been working this way for so long it seems normal. Maybe it was the case with an earlier version of VS, but it just seems like a fragile arrangement. VB.NET's history makes it too easy to fall back to a VB 6 style, which is disappointing considering it's my favorite language. I wish they'd have used a different keyword. I just don't think most developers, especially newbies, understand the difference between the way `var` works vs declaring everything an `object`. It *looks* the same. I try to take that into account when answering questions.

Comment: Although I suppose to be perfectly honest, I struggle to see the benefit of `var` even in C#. I don't use it myself very often because between my typing speed and Intellisense, it doesn't save me any steps. I see far more people confused about how the compiler interprets their code than I do people who struggle to type the types of a variable faster than their brain can think.

Comment: @Cody: I just tried it out in VS 2010: With all Options set to On (which is the default), saying `Dim x` by itself gives an **error** (not just a warning), saying `Option Strict On requires all variable declarations to have an 'As' clause.` So there's no way for him to shoot himself in the foot, unless the OP explicitly turns off one of these options... which is possible, but which I doubt will happen, given that he did not seem familiar with these options (or previous versions of VB).

Comment: @Cody: I use `var` *extensively* in C#, but *only* when the reader can infer the type easily from the right-hand side. So I frequently say, `int y = 5; var x = y;` because it's obvious that `y` is `int` (I wouldn't do this if `y` was declared far from `x`, though), but I never say `IEnumerator<T> o = ...; var x = o.Current;` because that's very vague. It not only saves me some time (I don't even have to *look* at intellisense), but it also makes things less cluttered, and (IMHO) easier to read.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Fair. I haven't revisited this in VS2010. It's good to know they've done it the Right Way, I suppose. And I guess since the older versions of VS (2003, 2005) are pretty much dead, there's less risk than I intuitively feel of people ending up with bad code. It's hard to abandon old habits and prejudices, especially without much compelling advantage to doing so. I regularly have VBA programmers argue that early binding is bad, late binding is better (!), and it's that kind of confusion that makes me seriously consider whether anonymous types in VB.NET are different enough from dynamic.

Comment: @Cody: Haha don't be too surprised at what the VBA programmers are saying -- my CS professor also argues that dynamic typing/late binding (e.g. in Scheme) is better than static typing/early binding, since it rids the programmer of the need to think about types when he is programming. I don't understand what's so nice about that either, since it just saves time at compile time, but causes you to spend much *more* time debugging bugs that you could've prevented... but yeah, I've seen people like that too. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's nuts. Not only are bugs 10 times easier to catch at compile time, I'm also smarter then because I just wrote the code. Debugging is much more difficult than writing the code in the first place. Looking back, I think I mostly just disagree with the article linked by the OP. I don't think it's particularly well-written, and I don't think it does a good job disambiguating between anonymous types and dynamic types. The time I've spent on Stack Overflow has given me real knee-jerk reactions to things that potentially encourage bad practices, because I see so many.

Comment: @Cody: Yeah... I was pretty surprised when my prof told me that too; I didn't know (still don't know) how exactly to feel about it, haha.
In this particular case, since the default options are "good" and since the OP didn't seem to be familiar with dynamically-typed VB, I don't think he'd be learning bad practices from this, but I guess this is a bit subjective.
Oh, and speaking of anonymous types and the DLR features: I never use them, period. I hate them with a fiery passion. :)

Answer (score 14):

Some flavors

```
    Dim b() As Byte 'b is nothing
    Dim b1(1023) As Byte 'b1 is an array of 1024 elements, all equal to 0
    Dim b2() As Byte = New Byte() {85, 99, 1, 255} 'four elements

    b = New Byte() {} 'zero element array
    b = New Byte() {1, 2} 'two element array
```

Inference is generally a bad idea.

Comment: accepted answer answers OP's question "Can you explain to me why this is happening?" This answer shows examples how to do it right. This is what I needed thanks.